# Side by Side Stacked Bar Chart totaling to 100% in Tableau

Tags: bar-chart, tableau-api, percentage, stacked-chart

I'm trying to visualize the SO Developer Survey in Tableau. I have a side-by-side stacked bar chart. On the x-axis I have job satisfaction, separated by gender. (So, columns: job satisfaction, gender, both are dimensions). On the y-axis I have "most important aspect of a job opportunity" (So, rows: measure values, with each value being a COUNT).

I would like each bar to total to 100% so for each value in measured values I have set the quick table calculation to "Percent of Total" and am computing using cell, but when I do so, every value appears to be equal/100% within the bars.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Each value should be some percentage, all totaling up to 100%.

I was trying to follow this tutorial: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/stacked-100-percent-bar-chart

Comment: Do you have a sample workbook you could share?

Comment: A screenshot of your Tableau screen would help alternatively. Including your measures/dimensions and the Rows/Columns shelf

Comment: you are using "side-by-side stacked bar chart".  stacked bar chart automatically adds up to 100%. but how are you creating sidebyside bar chart a sample workbook at tableau public gallery will help you make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

`Percent of total` computed by cell will always give you 100%. Tableau is telling you that each cell represents 100% of the value for that cell. You will need to change your `compute using` to get the correct answer.

Here is an example using the "superstore" data set that ships with Tableau. To calculate the percentage breakdown for each region I use the `Percent of total` table calculation and calculate it by "Pane" which means that the percentage is showing me a value per region (so, "technology" represents 33.999% of sales in the "central" region):

[image]